# NSString With Potential Different encoding?

Tags: ios

Got JSON response from server where it contains different fonts:

```
Action Movies @ googlefun.ɪɴғᴏ
```

I did

```
$ file -I
```

and found out that they have different encodings: `UTF8` and `US-ASCII` separately.

This breaks `[NSString boundingRectWithSize]`.

I tried `attributedString`, encoding converstions:

```
CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)convertedString, NULL, transform, YES);
```

or:

```
    tmpUTF8 = [strResp UTF8String]; //UTF8 =Action Movies @ googlefun.…™…¥“ì·¥è

    NSCharacterSet *charactersToRemove =
    [[ NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet ] invertedSet ];

    NSString *utf8ToBeTrimmed = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:tmpUTF8];
NSString *trimmedReplacement =
    [utf8ToBeTrimmed stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove ];
```

and got:
`trimmedReplacement = Action Movies @ googlefun.ɪɴғᴏ`

How do I either convert all the characters into the same encoding, or remove the bad characters at all?

Comment: UTF8 is superset of ASCII so you have to deal with UTF8